# How do I get an large icon align to the text in ::marker?

Tags: css, marker

I am using ::marker to display a material icon onto the left of the text. But the icon is not aligned to the text. How do I align it ?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
<title>Material Icons</title>
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.1/iconfont/material-icons.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<style type="text/css">
#query_builder
{
    display: list-item;
    margin-left: 50px; 
    font-size: 20px;           
}
#query_builder::marker
{
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    content: "query_builder";
    color:#b0bec5;
    border:1px solid #b0bec5;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-size:27.5px;       
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="width:240px;border:1px solid red;margin-top:0">        
        <p id="query_builder">Takes Less Than <strong>10 Minutes to Complete!</strong></p>
    </div>    

</body>
</html>
```

Even position:absolute; doesn't work in ::marker

Answer (score 0):

Styling pseudo class can be tricky and hard to customize

I would suggest to do it this way, it will be easier to customize:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Material Icons</title>
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.1/iconfont/material-icons.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <style type="text/css">
      #query_builder {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 50px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      #query_builder i {
        font-family: 'Material Icons';
        content: "query_builder";
        color: #b0bec5;
        border: 1px solid #b0bec5;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 27.5px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div style="width:240px;border:1px solid red;margin-top:0">
      <p id="query_builder">
        <i class="material-icons md-36">schedule</i>
        <span>Takes Less Than <strong>10 Minutes to Complete!</strong></span>
      </p>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

This is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1aryh3fL/29/)

Read more about it from [MD Getting Icons](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#getting-icons)

Explore Icons [MD Icons](https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline)

Comment: There's a specific reason why I want to use CSS instead of HTML when displaying icons - Google Search results are showing the text query_builder in the search result snippet. This I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo elements and `position: absolute`

```css
#query_builder {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#query_builder::before {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  content: "query_builder";
  color: #b0bec5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 27.5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.1/iconfont/material-icons.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<div style="width:240px;border:1px solid red;margin-top:0">
  <p id="query_builder">Takes Less Than <strong>10 Minutes to Complete!</strong></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, ::before works, but I was wondering why the same doesn't work for ::marker.